# Advise on SEO-friendly URL structures

Tags: mod-rewrite, seo

My site is written in php and has urls like this:

`http://mysite.com/index.php?m=apple&f=show&t=hello-world`

I want to change it to SEO friendly url.but i don't know which one is better:

`http://mysite.com/apple/hello-world`

or

`http://mysite.com/apple/hello-world.html`

would you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not include the `.html`. It doesn't help your users at all. In general, if it is good for users it is good for SEO.

Comment: +1 for "*if it is good for users it is good for SEO*" I wish more people thought like that, rather than "*if it is good for SEO it's good enough*".

Answer (score 2):

Try to avoid extensions where possible, as they may change over time, and URIs should remain static. Think about old sites that use the .cgi extension, and then migrated to another system, such as PHP. Although HTML is likely to be around for a long time, it too may change.

See [Cool URIs don't change](http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html) for a good introduction.